# Alert if the output of command is missing a particular string

Tags: python, perl, bash, shell

With `bash script/python/perl script`, is it possible to show if the output of a command without a string, e.g.

```
curl -i http://www.google.com


HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Location: http://www.google.com.hk/
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

What I want to do is:

1. If the output contains 302, print nothing
2. Else, print `302 is missed`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the result of the `curl|grep` silented as test :

```
if ! `curl -i -s http://www.google.com|grep -q 302` ; then echo "302 is missed" ; fi
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ grep -q 302 << EOF || echo "302 is missed"
> HTTP/1.1 302 Found
> Location: http://www.google.com.hk/
> Cache-Control: private
> Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
> EOF
$ grep -q 302 << EOF || echo "302 is missed"
> HTTP/1.1 312 Found
> Location: http://www.google.com.hk/
> Cache-Control: private
> Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
> EOF
302 is missed
```

Comment: Might want to `head -n 1` to avoid picking "302" somewhere else in the response

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like the following:

```
if [ ! `echo 302 | grep 302` ] ; then echo 302 is missed; fi
```

Where you can replace `echo 302` with any appropriate command ...

equivalently:

```
echo 302 | grep 302 > /dev/null || echo "302 is missed"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can tell `curl` to only output the http code, if that is all you are interested in.

For example:

```
$ curl -Is -w %{http_code} -o /dev/null http://stackoverflow.com
200
```

The curl options used above are:

- `-I`: fetch the HTTP-header only
- `-s`: silent.  Don't show progress
  meter or error messages
- `-w`: what to write out. In this case, only
  http_code
- `-o`: where to send output to

So you can add this into a condition as follows:

```
[[ $(curl -Is -w %{http_code} -o /dev/null http://stackoverflow.com) -ne 302 ]] && echo "302 is missed"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this would do the trick, though as always, test first.

```
perl -e '$pat = shift; print "$pat is missed\n" unless qx{@ARGV} =~ /\Q$pat\E/' 302 curl -i http://www.google.com
```